# Change image on scroll using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I'm trying to change the fixed logo when it scrolls.  So, when you load the page, it's one logo (logo500x398_trans.png) and when you scroll to a certain point, it changes to the other (logo500x398_trans2.png).  Here is the javascript that I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var scrolling = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
if (scrolling > 10) {
  jQuery( "body" ).addClass("fixed-header");
  }
else {
   jQuery( "body" ).removeClass("fixed-header");
  }

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrolling = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
   if (scrolling > 10) {
     jQuery( "body" ).addClass("fixed-header");
     newImageURL = "logo500x398_trans2.png";
     }
else {
    jQuery( "body" ).removeClass("fixed-header");
    newImageURL = "logo500x398_trans.png";
  }
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML we can't help. Please reproduce all your code on a JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry!  here is it:  https://jsfiddle.net/8zq5ksLp/#&togetherjs=bDNv7eLco3

Comment: There is a vanilla js solution, hope it works for you http://jsbin.com/jezoyajeyi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at your JSFiddle and found how you were currently styling the element with your logo. Here's a CSS solution that doesn't require you to add more JavaScript.

This code is in your `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .header-image .site-title > a { 
    background: url(http://209.35.52.135/~thtroofing/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo500x398_trans.png) no-repeat !important;
  }
</style>
```

Add a rule to it to change the image for a `.fixed-header` like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .header-image .site-title > a { 
    background: url(http://209.35.52.135/~thtroofing/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo500x398_trans.png) no-repeat !important;
  }
  .header-image.fixed-header .site-title > a { 
    background-image: url(http://209.35.52.135/~thtroofing/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/logo500x398_trans2.png) !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: That still requires you to add a class to the element with javascript.

Comment: @MiguelCabrera I said it doesn't require him to add JavaScript. It utilizes the class his JS is already adding.

Comment: You said pure CSS solution. That is obviously not a pure css solution. Without Javascript it wouldn't work.

Comment: @MiguelCabrera My bad, fixed that wording.

Comment: You could also make it more concise by just styling the fixed-header class url image property. It would overwrite the html and so you would only need to style one property.

Answer (score 0):

I would create two separate css classes for each image and then toggle them at different points. Also keep in mind that scrolltop is in pixels so 10 pixels will seem like they hardly scroll at all.

```
.imgclass1 {
    background-image: url("1.jpg");
}
.imgclass2 {
    background-image: url("2.jpg");
}
```

and then toggle the classes like so.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var scrolling = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scrolling > 10) {
      $( "body" ).addClass("imgclass1");
      $("body").removeClass("imgclass2");
   } else {
      $("body").removeClass("imgclass1");
      $( "body" ).addClass("imgclass2");
}
```